# MySql queries are taking more than 5-10minutes to give results

Tags: mysql, sql, database, ubuntu-18.04

Below are the problems we are facing.

on-premise Server Config: 2Core CPU, 8GB Ram, 1TB HDD (200GB for DB).

MySQL server version 5.7.30

OS : Ubuntu Server 18.04 LTS.

issue description:

1. Not able to take a backup of MySQL database via mysqldump query. I tried it and it's been more than 24 hours but still, it was taking the backup. (I tried taking backup of the single table also which is having some **30.000.000 rows** still the same issue).
2. We are having two big tables for storing some data, whenever we are performing any query to these tables it is taking more than 5-10 minutes to give the results. (no. of records is around **40.000.000 in each table**).
3. Not showing any MySQL CPU consumption while performing queries in these tables.
4. I couldn't see any MySQL error logs generated on this particular day.
5. I also restarted the mysql server.

I request somebody to help me what is wrong here, is it because of the number of records in that table or the server configuration is not able to handle this request or something else.

Comment: Please do not use [crore](https://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crore) on stackoverflow, because most readers will not know that its the equivalent of `10.000.000`

Comment: Honestly I think it's hard for us to help you without knowing anything about table definitions and queries you're performing.
It could be a problem of keys and indexes, but I'm just guessing

Comment: Just a side note: are you sure you cannot design db differently just to avoid having huge tables?

Comment: 8GB RAM could be a little amount maybe. About HDD: is that SSD or mechanic?

Comment: What's the query? You can't solve this with IT only. The solution is probably on the software side.

Comment: Please post for ONE of your slow queries - A) complete QUERY as TEXT, B) EXPLAIN SELECT ......; C) SHOW CREATE TABLE tbl_name; and D) SHOW TABLE STATUS WHERE name LIKE 'tbl_name';   for analysis.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to solve the backup issue by using mydumper instead of mysqldump since mydumper is multi threaded.

apt install mydumper

Please show us your query and the output of show create table <table_name> of the table you're querying.

Comment: This could have been a comment